# How To Create Reports Using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, odbc, report

I am new to Visual Studio 2010 C#. I'm creating an application which creates a report. The information that will be displayed in the report is from the MySQL Server. I already installed the Crystal Reports. However, I do have some problems with getting data from MySQL because I can't find the data from MySQL. The data shown in the Report Creation Wizard in not the database files in MySQL but the forms I created in C#. Please help.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The tag 'reporting-services' is invalid for your question

Comment: You should creat a new connection in order to see your mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataAccess.Connection.Close();
DataAccess.Connection.Open();
DataAccess.dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT sales.qty, sales.ord_date, sales.payterms, stores.stor_name, stores.stor_id, titles.title_id, titles.title, titles.price, (sales.qty * titles.price) AS Total FROM sales INNER JOIN stores ON sales.stor_id = stores.stor_id INNER JOIN  titles ON sales.title_id = titles.title_id", DataAccess.Connection);

DataAccess.dataTable = new DataTable();
DataAccess.dataAdapter.Fill(DataAccess.dataTable);
Bind.DataSource = DataAccess.dataTable;
string temp = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[0][3].ToString();

Excel.Application xlApp2 = new Excel.Application();
xlApp2.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook Workbook2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Add(1);
Excel.Worksheet Worksheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)Workbook2.Sheets[1];

Worksheet2.Cells[1, 1] = "Sales Report";
Worksheet2.Cells[3, 1] = temp.ToUpper();
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 2] = "Order Date";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 3] = "Payment Terms";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 4] = "Store Name";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 5] = "Store ID";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 6] = "Title ID";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 7] = "Book Title";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 8] = "Unit Price";
Worksheet2.Cells[4, 9] = "Total Price";

int intCount2 = 5;
int TotalRec = 0;
int finecort = 0;
decimal cost = 0;
decimal cost1 = 0;

for (int n = 0; n < DataAccess.dataTable.Rows.Count; n++)
{
    if (DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][3].ToString().Equals(temp))
    {
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "C"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][0];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "B"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][1];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "D"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][3];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "E"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][4];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "F"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][5];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "G"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][6];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "H"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][7];
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "I"] = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][8];

        intCount2++;
        TotalRec++;
        finecort++;
        cost += Convert.ToDecimal(DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][8]);
        cost1 += Convert.ToDecimal(DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][8]);
    }
    else
    {
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "B"] = ("Number of records in " + temp + " group are" + TotalRec + " and the cost is R" + cost1);
        TotalRec = 0;
        cost1 = 0;
        temp = DataAccess.dataTable.Rows[n][3].ToString();
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 2, "A"] = temp.ToUpper();

        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "B"] = "Order Date";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "C"] = "Quantity";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "D"] = "Store Name";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "E"] = "Store ID";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "F"] = "Title ID";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "G"] = "Book Title";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "H"] = "Unit Price";
        Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "I"] = "Total Price";

        intCount2 += 4;
    }
    Worksheet2.Cells.Columns.AutoFit();

}

Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2, "B"] = ("Number of records in " + temp + " group=" + TotalRec);
Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 2 ,"A"] = "2013 Sales Report records added upto ";
Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 2, "B"] = finecort;
Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "A"] = "Grrand Total of all records ";
Worksheet2.Cells[intCount2 + 3, "B"] = "R"+cost;
Worksheet2.Range[Worksheet2.Cells[1, "A"], Worksheet2.Cells[1, "I"]].Merge();
Worksheet2.Cells.Columns.AutoFit();
DataAccess.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: what does this answer mean about creating Crystal Reports report over MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-crystalreports.html) I found the solution that fits for you question.

Crystal Reports can use an **ODBC DSN** to connect to a database from which you to extract data and information for reporting purposes.

> Note There is a known issue with certain versions of Crystal Reports
>   where the application is unable to open and browse tables and fields
>   through an ODBC connection. Before using Crystal Reports with MySQL,
>   please ensure that you have update to the latest version, including
>   any outstanding service packs and hotfixes. For more information on
>   this issue, see the Business) Objects Knowledgebase for more
>   information.

Follow these steps:

1. Create a **DSN using the Data Sources (ODBC)** tool. You can either specify a complete database, including user name and password, or you can build a basic DSN and use Crystal Reports to set the user name and password.
2. Start the Cross-Tab Report Wizard, either by clicking the option on the Start Page. Expand the **Create New Connection folder**, then **expand the ODBC (RDO) folder** to obtain a list of ODBC data sources.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

     int count1,count2;
        clsInfor.northCON.Open();
        clsInfor.dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Discontinued, QuantityPerUnit FROM Products", clsInfor.northCON);
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        clsInfor.dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application(); //creating a new application
        app.Visible = true;

        Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Add(1); // creating an instance of the workbook 
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1]; // creating an instance of the worksheet

        ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, "A"]).Value2 = "Report"; // creating the header of the report
        ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[2, "B"]).Value2 = "Number of products per Cat";//creating the names of the colomns in the excell spreedsheet
        ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[2, "C"]).Value2 = "Number of products that have been discontinued";

        ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[4, "D"]).Value2 = "Tot number of Prod";

        for (count1 = 0; count1 < dataTable.Rows.Count; count1++)
        {
            for (count2 = 0; count2 < dataTable.Columns.Count; count2++)
            {
                sheet.Cells[count1 + 3, count2 + 2] = dataTable.Rows[count1][count2];
            }
            sheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        string xmlFileName = (@"C:");
        xmlDocument.Load(xmlFileName);

        XmlElement xItem = xmlDocument.CreateElement("item");


        XmlElement xmlSubElement1 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("todoID");
        xmlSubElement1.InnerText = todoID;
        xItem.AppendChild(xmlSubElement1);

        XmlElement xmlSubElement2 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("todoDate");
        xmlSubElement2.InnerText = todoDate;
        xItem.AppendChild(xmlSubElement2);

        XmlElement xmlSubElement3 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("todoTime");
        xmlSubElement3.InnerText = todoTime;
        xItem.AppendChild(xmlSubElement3);

        XmlElement xmlSubElement4 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("todoItem");
        xmlSubElement4.InnerText = todoItem;
        xItem.AppendChild(xmlSubElement4);

        XmlElement xmlSubElement5 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("todoStatus");
        xmlSubElement5.InnerText = todoStatus;
        xItem.AppendChild(xmlSubElement5);

        XmlElement xmlSubElement6 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("UserID");
        xmlSubElement6.InnerText = UserID;
        xItem.AppendChild(xmlSubElement6);


        //xmlDocument.AppendChild(xItem);
        xmlDocument.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(xItem);
        // then finally save
        xmlDocument.Save(@"C:");
        xmlmsg ="A new item has been added to the to do list";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btndlt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
        string id = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string path = @"";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TheToDoList/item[todoID='" + id + "']");
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        doc.Save(path);
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Record Deleted Successfully");
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
        int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
        string path = @"";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TheToDoList/item[todoID='" + id1 + "']");
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        doc.Save(path);

                //    //Load the XML File
                    doc.Load(path);


                    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("TheToDoList");
                    XmlElement Subroot = doc.CreateElement("item");
                    XmlElement todoID = doc.CreateElement("todoID");
                    XmlElement todoDate = doc.CreateElement("todoDate");
                    XmlElement todoTime = doc.CreateElement("todoTime");
                    XmlElement todoItem = doc.CreateElement("todoItem");
                    XmlElement todoStatus = doc.CreateElement("todoStatus");
                    XmlElement UserID = doc.CreateElement("UserID");
                    //Add the values for each nodes
                    todoID.InnerText = row.Cells[0].ToString();
                    todoDate.InnerText = row.Cells[1].ToString();
                    todoTime.InnerText = row.Cells[2].ToString();
                    todoItem.InnerText = row.Cells[3].ToString();
                    todoStatus.InnerText = row.Cells[4].ToString();
                    UserID.InnerText = row.Cells[5].ToString();
                    //Construct the document
                    doc.AppendChild(root);
                    root.AppendChild(Subroot);
                    Subroot.AppendChild(todoID);
                    Subroot.AppendChild(todoDate);
                    Subroot.AppendChild(todoTime);
                    Subroot.AppendChild(todoItem);
                    Subroot.AppendChild(todoStatus);
                    Subroot.AppendChild(UserID);
                    doc.Save(path);
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Record Edited Successfully");
```